# SQL Merge update

Tags: sql, sql-server

my merge query

```sql
  MERGE Povertytgt t 
    USING Povertyrsc s
        ON (s.Incomegroup = t.Incomegroup )
 WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET 
        t.CountbyGroup = s.CountbyGroup;
```

and got error

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

this is resource table

```
CountbyGroup    IncomeGroup ID
78              Limit 2 - $4,012    
17              Limit 2 - $4,012
```

This is target table

```
CountbyGroup    IncomeGroup       
0               Limit 2 - $4,012     
0               Limit 3 - $4,956     
0               Limit 4 - $5,899
```

I expect this result

```
CountbyGroup    IncomeGroup 
78              Limit 2 - $4,012    
17              Limit 3 - $4,956    
0               Limit 4 - $5,899
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If you're getting this error then a straight update will mask the fact that you're changing some rows more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `update`?

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.CountbyGroup = s.CountbyGroup;
    FROM Povertytgt t JOIN
         Povertyrsc s
         ON s.Incomegroup = t.Incomegroup;
```

You don't specify the error, so I don't know if this will fix it.  But it is a simpler approach.

and got error

Comment: Hey , thank you.Update work.  I just want update no insert and no delete. I think I know why I got the error. There is duplicate from source table.